# domain network with DHCP + NAT

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, nat

I'm configuring a virtual network on an esx server.
I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 configured with these roles:
- active directory domain services
- DHCP server
- DNS Server
- Network Policy and Access Services.

The Windows Server 2008 R2 has 2 network adapters. The first one (which works) has access to the internet and has these settings:
IP: 192.168.27.40
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.27.1

DNS: 192.168.200.14 (This is needed for internet connection in the virtual network)

The second one, my private adapter, should give the internet obtained via the first adapter to my clients in the private network. That's why I configured NAT (via this link, without step 3-4-5 because I have DHCP already: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx)

The second adapter has these settings:
IP: 20.0.0.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: (empty)
DNS: 127.0.0.1

Can you tell me what setting I have wrong? I want to use the internet on the clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vmware adapter changing from VMXNET3 to E1000 was the key